# How to remove Japan-locale, and use US-locale in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, locale

Previously, I add japanese keyboard language into my windows 7 (via control panel). But, recently I remove it, so I just use English locale.
But my command prompt still using Japanese style, you can see below:


[image]

In the picture, the Get-Culture just display the English-locale, there is no Japanese. But the '\' character is replaced by 'yen' character. How to remove Japanese locale properly from my windows 7?

Answer (score 0):

I tried this on Windows 7 and it worked...

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/change-the-system-locale